# how to move angular 1 project in Cordova run without local server

Tags: angularjs, cordova

I run angular V-1 project in local server in my machine.  I convert that project in cordova. How to run that project in mobile with server

Comment: you need to add platform android, create an apk (if android), install it in android device and run

Comment: Thanks. I solved that issue.....